# QSharedPointer Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qsharedpointer

I have a program that makes heavy use of `QSharedPointer`. When I execute my program it runs fine, but when I debug it with GDB it starts throwing errors. `"Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap"` is thrown in the following code:

```
QSharedPointer<PersistentList> p = 
   PersistentList::createEx(wrap("abc")).dynamicCast<PersistentList>();    

QSharedPointer<IPersistentCollection> c = p->empty(); // Error thrown after this line    

QSharedPointer<IPersistentCollection> ASeq::empty()
{
    return QSharedPointer<EmptyList>(new EmptyList());
}
```

If I disable the `p->empty()` line the program runs just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  when I read your code, as p is based on a list, then doesn't p->empty() return a bool rather than a pointer?

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, but actually in this case p->empty() returns an empty list....I should probably rename the function as it's only ever used for testing.

Comment: What createEx does? Could you post it's body? Also more code context would be helpful. It seems that you have minor memory managment error

Comment: Well as mentioned above if I comment the 2nd line the error doesn't occur. Since that line does not actually touch p at all, it can't really be a problem with createEx....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely elsewhere in your code. Run it under Valgrind and see if you're touching any memory that's not yours, or using uninitialized data, etc.